# ng-animate and ng-if cause transition not to played in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, css, css-transitions, ng-animate

I have a simple div which has a transition. It transitions from a yellow background to a red one.

```
<div class="foo" ng-class="{'foo-visible': vm.visible}">
```

The transition is played once the foo--visible class is added to the div.

This works fine in Chrome, IE...etc.

However once I add a wrapper div around it, the transition stops working in Internet Explorer (tested with IE10).

```
<div class="foo--wrapper" ng-if="vm.visible">
    <div class="foo" ng-class="{'foo--visible': vm.visible}">
</div>
```

I need to include ngAnimate in this case. Then it works in Chrome, but in IE I immediately get the red div, the transition is never played. No transitionstart (IE only) or transitionend events are fired.

Here's a plunker illustrating the issue:

http://plnkr.co/vpJzudnLxTwoJGZoZaNd

Does anybody have an idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This plnkr adds two similar boxes to yours. http://plnkr.co/edit/lkyWHu?p=preview

```
<div ng-if="vm.visible">
  <div class="animate-box animate-if">
    <h2>Inner Class</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div  class="animate-box animate-if" ng-if="vm.visible">
  <div>
    <h2>Outer Class</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "Outer" works in both IE and Chrome.

Chrome iterates the child animation for "Inner" in a way that makes sense. Internet Explorer, as for your example, does not.

On closing, neither do the child animation because the delay to remove the parent is zero.

An interesting point though, IE and Chrome appear to work the same for the authoritative answer at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateChildren

The CSS I used was:

```
.animate-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.animate-if.ng-animate {
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I found a much better answer to this at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2909-child-animations-have-to-take-the-magical-transition-delay-into-account-in-angularjs.htm